# is pre-approval require for my website's Paypal gateway?

Tags: paypal, gateway

i'm creating a website and i will sell my digital learning products about football betting(there is no gambling or prizing in my website) with my paypal premier.i use woocommerce in my website.
please see this link:https://www.paypal.com/st/webapps/mpp/ua/acceptableuse-full
if i don't pre-approve my website what will happen?will they close my account?
do i need to preapprove my website before use it as gateway in my website?
If yes,after i send them my website activity and my contact detals to them what will they do?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a question for stackoverflow, but is more for https://money.stackexchange.com

But, to answer your question, you should seek pre-approval or paypal may freeze your funds and stop serving you without notice. They may still do this anyway but pre-approval significantly reduces this risk.